# If you plug a 100v mini split AC into a wall outlet rated at 15a or 20a, what possible complications could occur, if any?

Tags: electrical, wiring, hvac, receptacle

A 110v mini split AC is typically wired to an AC disconnect and then into the breaker box. However, many have simply wired it directly into a standard outlet receptacle, or even to a standard plug, to plug into a receptacle as a standard appliance, and without any AC disconnect.

Assuming you used a proper gauge appliance wire running from the unit to the outlet, what potential complications could occur from such an endeavor, or would it be perfectly fine, as the appliance is a 110v appliance?

Do beware as this is NOT discussing a 220v unit which is NOT possible in this manner.

Comment: If unit instructions and/or code say no, then it will not pass inspection and/or your insurance company will not be happy(possible denied claims).  What amperage does unit require?

Comment: What is the ampacity of this unit? Lots of information in the answers, first if the unit is cord connected you know with a plug, the plug can be the disconnect but it has to be in the manufactures instructions to be code compliant. Tired of all the downvotes from wannabe internet electricians so that’s all I will say.

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking, a load will go to a higher voltage *before* it goes to higher amperage.  For instance if a load needs 3600W provisioned, it will go to 240V/15A rather than 120V/30A.  Higher amps require more expensive wire, for no useful use.

As such, if your heat pump is 120V, it is probably low amperage - I would bet no more than 16 amps.  That's not so bad, as modern heat pumps have excellent SEER as high as 20 - 16A x 120V x 20 SEER = 38,000 BTU.

Code says a cord-and-plug connection counts as a disconnect switch.

The issue is NEC 110.3(B) which requires following the instructions that came with the unit. If that forbids a cord-and-plug connection, then you can't do it.  This is a UL listed unit, and UL either has good reason for requiring that instruction, or simply has not been asked to test the unit in that configuration for durability and weather resistance, so they have no idea if it is safe.

Answer (score 2):

The reason the AC units are hard wired into a disconnect switch is so the servicing technician can disconnect the power to the unit and make sure no one else can turn it back on. Maybe if you had the proper gauge appliance cord and plug rated for outside use (good luck) and a properly covered GFCI outlet, that would serve as a disconnect provided that it was next to the outside unit. The bottom line is how do the instructions say the unit has to be installed? Probably not the way you want to do it. These units are certified based on being installed as the instructions say. Cords outside are dangerous which is why you don't see many of them and in many cases not permitted by the local codes. Plus, animals love to gnaw on them and eat through the insulation. Then you grab the cord and ZAP!!  Bye Bye. You mentioned not discussing 240V, more people are killed with 120V than 240V.

Comment: A Jack what is the difference in a cord and type TC cable that most splits come with? It’s not about animals chewing that is more likely in the attic and crawl space.

Comment: @EdBeal I was under the impression the OP was asking about using an appliance cord like you'd find on a widow AC unit not TC cable since he didn't mention any cable coming with the unit. Sorry you're not around. Always reversed any DV's I saw on your posts.

Comment: TC cable is what many manufacturers use to power the inside unit(s) that is tun with the line sets, thanks, on the down votes I got tired of wannabes downvotes, my new job as the signing supervisor managing a master permit program for a large hospital has me not coming here often.

Comment: Good point about the AC disconnect, now I understand why it's there. And why pulling the plug is also fine as the AC disconnect. To keep the HVAC technician safe. But by outside it would be in a screened porch, so no animals to gnaw it.

Answer (score 0):

Function wise if you had a plug designed durable enough to handle the motor inrush currents then it could work.

NEC wise you get lots of complications. You must comply with the *UL/CSA/ETL Listing*, if it says you can use a plug you are good to go. Otherwise I don't think the code would allow it. Section 422 for appliances specifies that and when a receptacle is allowed and some limitations, but it is not implicitly permitted in the Air Conditioning section 440 to serve as a disconnect. The Disconnecting means section does mention cord and plug connected equipment, but I think it is referring to portable units with factory cord connections.

If you try to claim that what isn't prohibited is allowed then the rating of an allowed disconnect is required to be 115% of the branch circuit. The code only allows receptacles larger than branch circuit for dedicated receptacles, one or more duplex receptacles on the circuit would not be allowed, so an existing circuit would likely not qualify. The label will also limit overcurrent protection size which would allow breaker or fuses, it is possible it could specify fuses, if it does just breakers are not allowed.

Comment: If the unit is supplied with a plug in connection that is a legal disconnect.